# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD in NDIS.sys, with MemTest passing - what's the cause?

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, bsod, hardware-failure, boot

I just got a Blue Screen of Death with `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`, in `NDIS.sys`.

My hardware:

- Intel P4 Northwoord 2.4 GHz
- Intel D850EMV2 board
- 4 x 256 MB RDRAM
- other stuff

Context:

- Computer was doing fine for most of the day (running Windows XP, doing desktop work).
- Suddenly it freezes: I still get the display, but it doesn't answer network traffic nor respond to keyboard/mouse.
- Restarting and trying to boot Windows XP gets you the BSOD either during boot or at the Welcome screen.
- Ran MemTest+ 4.20, no errors.

What could be the possible causes?

**Update 1:** smartctl says:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   200   200   051    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   167   164   021    -    2616
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    857
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   200   200   140    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   100   253   051    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    541
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   051    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--C-   100   100   051    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    838
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   110   095   000    -    33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   200   200   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   200   200   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   P--R--   200   200   051    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning
```

Comment: Try checking the health of the hard drives with a SMART monitoring tool.

Comment: @einpoklum take a look at the hard drive.  http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli: Will do.

Comment: upload the .dmp files so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Comment: Can't reproduce due to HW changes, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Bad ram slot? I had a similar issue with my laptop, tried swapping out ram, tried new HDD, tried many things, ultimately just got a new computer.

Comment: How could this be the case if I pass MemTest?

Comment: again, upload the dumps

Comment: I have no solid answer as to why this is the case but I'm giving an example of how my system was fixed, we have found that it was able to read the ram no problem. Then, after many other attempts of swapping the RAM that is was manufacturer fault because of how the system will ALWAYS fault out on a particular sector of RAM. We couldn't explain why.